# How does the slipstream of a falling object affect flying animals near it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, estimation, air

I am the script supervisor for a short film being created by several of my friends. In the script, it specifies that a bird is sucked downward by the passage of a large falling crate. I am now, however, curious about the physics beyond this specific instance.

Put more generally, an object falling through air creates a slipstream. Given a great enough speed and size, is it possible for the air behind or near this object to pull flying animals, or even vehicles, along with it? How big, roughly, would this object have to be in order to do this?

Comment: Have you seen a speeding car sweep up dust and leaves behind it? That should give you an idea.

Comment: That's not a "slipstream". That's called a wake, a Carman wake, actually. There are swirls on the outer boundary of the wake, swirling inwards, they can get the object into the wake. To assess if a bird can be sucked into the wake, we need to have a look at the drag force formula and to assess the parameters that go into it. One think that can be said with some degree of certainty is that the object's size must be on the order of the bird's size (because the swirls, usually, are on the order of the object's size, at least, in the part of the wake closer to the object).